# get widgets by name from layout

Tags: python, qt, widget

How should I proceed if I want to get an especific widget from a layout in python Qt?

What I have done so far:

```
for i in range(self.ui.horizontalLayout_14.count()): 
    #here it does fail
    name = self.ui.horizontalLayout_14.itemAt(i).objectName()

    #if the above would had worked, then I could do something like this for example
    if "button" in name:
        self.ui.horizontalLayout_14.itemAt(i).widget().close()
```

Note that, for the example, I am using `button` but It might be whatever widget inside the layout, lineEdit, or comboBox, labels, etc etc, but not all of them though.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

The problem is that `itemAt()` function returns the `QLayoutItem` and not a widget. So you have to call the `QLayoutItem::widget()` function to get the containing widget, i.e.:

```
name = self.ui.horizontalLayout_14.itemAt(i).widget().objectName()
```

**UPDATE**

However, you can do the same much easier with using the `QObject::findChild()` function. I.e.:

```
widget = self.ui.findChild(QPushButton, "button")
# Check whether the returned widget is null...
```

Comment: yes you were right, it works now, thanks!. The update looks fine for me as well. Great. I will accept this as an answer as soon as it lets me